# When posting a comment I get a broken image icon rather than "working" animation

Tags: support, status-completed

Well the title says it all really.

Missing "working" image on posting comments.

Comment: Me too - was about to file the same report....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We forgot to include the .gif animations in the deployment; this should be fixed now.

Comment: Testing adding a comment - it works, at least here on meta.